# How to reduce data retrieval time from MongoDB using JavaRDD in spark?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, rdd

I want to read data from MongoDB having more then 60 million data using JavaRDD and do further data analysis on it.

I am using this for report generation so JavaRDD building multiple times and taking a lot of time.

Because it loads the whole data every time after that fetch data based on MongoDB query criteria.

Is there any solution that can improve the performance?

Can I load data from MongoDB only which lies in given criteria instead of loading whole data?

Comment: Its being worked on see: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-101

Comment: Thanks for comment Ross @Ross